# Cannot create a trigger using console that depends on a crawler in AWS Glue

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-glue, aws-glue-workflow

I am trying to create a trigger in Glue that would watch a set of my crawlers and then trigger an ETL job. Based on the documentation, this should be fairly straightforward.

However when I log into the console and try to create a conditional trigger, the only option I get is to watch other jobs and not crawlers. This got me confused. Is this a deprecated functionality?

For the time being I will use Cloudformation instead, but am now curious if that is also not going to be supported in the future.

Comment: You can schedule it using step functions

Comment: Either you can reach out to AWS support requesting for feature enhancement or use AWS Lambda trigger to start your Glue job by looking at the crawler state.